# w3m - work offline for email HTML attachement preview

Tags: html, mutt, attachments, w3m

I'm using w3m for reading HTML mail in Mutt. I'm not using `auot_view` but rather open the HTML attachements in w3m. w3m seems to download resources like stylesheets and images by default (it has just showed me StackOverflow logo preview, in terminal!). Is there any switch or a hack to make w3m work offline? Graphical email clients usually just format the HTML without fetching anything linked from it.

I'd also like an easy way to make it work online again for example when there's a link in the URL I'd like to follow. If I launch w3m via script that sets a null HTTP proxy or puts w3m in isolated network namespace, I'll not have an easy way to make it talk to the Internet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly there is no option in w3m to put it in offline-mode. But you should be able to remove access to the network for the w3m (or any other) process by starting it like like this:

```
unshare -r -n w3m
```

This effectively removes the networknamespace for the processes thus turning it incapable of requesting anything.

Check out this related [Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/block-network-access-of-a-process) for details